# Fetching TextView Top/Y immediately after changing text size

Tags: android, textview, rect

I am trying to translate a TextView based on the difference of its Y-value, and another Views Y-value. Before i translate the TextView, i change its text size, effectively changing its Y value. The problem that occurs is the TextViews Y-value isn't being updated immediately after a change in text size

E.G. Both log statements below yield same results

```
Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(productTotal.getY()));
productTotal.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(productTotal.getY()));
```

However, if i were to run this code again, i would receive a updated Y-value. My guess is because the logic below is called at the press of a button, so perhaps the TextViews Y-value is being cached until the next Frame Update? Anyways, getTop, getY, getHeight are all giving me improper values. What suggestions do you have to fetch the updated Y-value immediately after changing the TextViews text size? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the value for `getY()` immediately, you will have to anticipate some of the work that will occur when the view undergoes the layout processing. This will primarily involve making a call to `View#measure()` as follows:

```
TextView productTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
int textSize = 100;

Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(productTotal.getY()));
productTotal.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(productTotal.getY()));
ViewGroup parent = ((ViewGroup) productTotal.getParent());
int widthMeasureSpec =
    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int heightMeasureSpec =
    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
productTotal.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(productTotal.getY()));
// No getMeasuredY(), so we have to back into the new value for "Y".
Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(productTotal.getBottom() - productTotal.getMeasuredHeight()));
```

See the [doc for measure()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#measure(int,%20int)).

> [measure] is called to find out how big a view should be. The parent supplies constraint information in the width and height parameters.

Comment: I found a much simpler solution where i just anticipated the Y-Value post-textSize change. I'd still be interested in seeing why this is an issue to begin with however. Does the android framework cache the bound values of a View until the next layout pass?